# My mouse has two buttons on the side. How do I program them to change the current song?

Tags: windows-8, mouse, accessories

I got a new wireless sandstrom mouse and a new keyboard. The new keyboard has a play/pause button but no song forward or song back button. I would like to know how to set that up on Windows 8.

Comment: please post the exact model of you product.

Comment: Did you download / run the software or driver that came? If so, there is possibly an updated GUI in Control Panel -> Mouse which may let you set it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are struggling to find a driver for your mouse which achieves this, you could try using software to map the extra buttons to specific events. One example would be [X Mouse](http://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm). The linked page says that it supports Windows 8.

Comment: Or use [autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)'s `XButton1` and `XButton2`